# Using ThreadLocal in tandem with Volatile gives unpredictable results

Tags: java, volatile, thread-local

I was reading through Java Memory model and was playing with volatile. I wanted to check how Volatile will work in tandem with ThreadLocal. As per definition ThreadLocal has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable whereas when you use volatile keyword then JVM guarantees that all writes and subsequent reads are done directly from the memory. Based on the high level definitions i knew what i was trying to do will give unpredictable results. But just out of curiosity wanted to ask if someone can explain in more details as if what is going on in the background. Here is my code for your reference...

```
public class MyMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ThreadLocal<MyClass> local = new ThreadLocal<>();
        local.set(new MyClass());

        for(int i=0;i<5; i++){
            Thread thread = new Thread(local.get());
            thread.start();
        }

    }

}


public class MyClass implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean flag = false;

    public void printNameTillFlagIsSet(){
        if(!flag)
        System.out.println("Flag is on for : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        else
            System.out.println("Flag is off for : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        printNameTillFlagIsSet();
        this.flag = true;       
    }


}
```

Comment: Your thread local variable is not shared between threads, it's allocated on stack. Not sure then what the question is.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the purpose of `ThreadLocal`? You only use it in a single thread in a single method. You could as well use a local variable. It wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: So what are trying to accomplish/prove?

Comment: @Kan - Actually what i am trying to implement here is create a ThreadLocal<MyClass> and inside declare one of its member variable as volatile. Now in such a scenario how will JVM behave?? As you mentioned that in case of a threadlocal everything is copied on to stack and nothing is shared however volatile works exactly opposite. I hope i am clear on atleast the intent.

Comment: @Tudor - As said just out of curiosity i wanted to ask if someone can better explain as to what is going on in the background. Does the explanation ends as "the result is simply unpredictable" or does it go a little deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big problems:

1)  As many pointed out, you are not using ThreadLocal properly so you don't actually have any "thread local" variables.

2) Your code is equivalent to:

```
MyClass someInstance = new Class();
for (...)
   ... new Thread(someInstance);
```

so you should expect to see 1 `on` and 4 `off`.  However your code is badly synchronized, so you get random results.  The problem is that although you declare `flag` as `volatile`, this is not enough for good synchronization since you do the check on `flag` in printNameTillFlagSet and then change the `flag` value just after that method call in `run`.  There is a gap here where many threads can see the `flag` as true.  You should check the `flag` value and change it *within a synchronized block*.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you create a ThreadLocal reference as a local variable of your main method. You then store an instance of `MyClass` in it and then give that same reference of `MyClass` to 5 threads created in the main method.

The resulting output of the program is unpredictable since the threads are not synchronized against each other. At least one thread will see the flag as `false` the other four could see the flag as either `true` or `false` depending on how the thread execution is scheduled by the OS. It is possible that all 5 threads could see the flag as `false`, or 1 could see it `false` and 4 see it `true` or anything in between.

The use of a ThreadLocal has no impact on this run at all based on the way you are using it.

Comment: Yes, if you don't use `threadLocal.initialValue()`, ThreadLocal does basically nothing.

Comment: @toto2 - it has nothing to do w/ using initialValue().  the ThreadLocal is used exclusively on the "main" thread, and is therefore useless.

Comment: @jtahlborn I guess you know what I mean: you do need to define initialValue() somewhere to have actual "thread local" values.  See the answer by John Vint on how to use ThreadLocal properly.

Comment: @toto2 - you don't _need_ to use initialValue() to have actual thread locals,  you just need to call set() on different threads.

Answer (score 4):

As most have pointed out you have deeply misunderstood ThreadLocal.  This is how I would write it to be more accurate.

```
public class MyMainClass {

    private static final ThreadLocal<MyClass> local = new ThreadLocal<>(){
           public MyClass initialValue(){
               return new MyClass();
           }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        local.set(new MyClass());

        for(int i=0;i<5; i++){
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                  public void run(){
                       local.get().printNameTillFlagIsSet();
                       local.get().run();
                       local.get().printNameTillFlagIsSet();
                  }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

So here five different instances of MyClass are created.  Each thread will have their own accessible copy of each MyClass.  That is Thread created at i = 0 will always have a different instance of MyClass then i = 1,2,3,4 despite how many local.get() are done.

The inner workings are a bit complicated but it can be done similar to

```
ConcurrentMap<Long,Thread> threadLocalMap =...;
public MyClass get(){
   long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
   MyClass value = threadLocalMap.get(id);
   if(value == null){
      value = initialValue();
      threadLocalMap.put(id,value);
   }
    return value;
}
```

To further answer your question about the volatile field.  It is in essence useless here.  Since the field itself is 'thread-local' there will be no ordering/memory issues that can occur.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't divinize the JVM. ThreadLocal is a regular class. Inside it uses a map from current thread ID into an object instance. So that the same ThreadLocal variable could have its own value for each thread. That's all. Your variable exists only in the main thread, so it doesn't make any sence.

The volatile is something about java code optimization, It just stops all possible optimizations which allow avoid redundant memory reads/writes and execution sequence re-orderings. It is important for expecting some particular behaviour in multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 0):

You main thread where you have a ThreadLocal object is being passed to all the threads. So the same instance is being passed.

So its as good as

```
new Thread(new MyClass());
```

What you could try is have an object being called by different threads with a thread local variable. This will be a proper test for ThreadLocal where each thread will get its own instance of the variable.

Comment: This is where my confusion is because when i use the code given by you my results are different than what i am getting right now.

Comment: Can you post both results?  the moment you do local.get you will get a reference to the object which is in main. There may be a difference in outputs because of the slight overhead you introduce making the call. But it should be inconsistent in both cases.

Comment: @Sid, you meant: `MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); for ... new Thread(myClass);`

Comment: @Toto no i meant  Thread thread = new Thread(local.get()); is same as  Thread thread = new Thread(new MyClass()); as the local.get will return the same in main in the loop.

Comment: if i use new Thread(new MyClass) then value of my volatile flag remains true for all the threads since i am providing a new instance every time to the thread i.e 'Flag is on for : Thread-0, Flag is on for : Thread-2, Flag is on for : Thread-3 etc'. However when i use the code posted above my results vary i.e. 'Flag is on for : Thread-0, Flag is on for : Thread-2, Flag is **off** for : Thread-0, Flag is **off** for : Thread-0'

Comment: @Sid no, `local.get()` here returns the exact same instance.  You would need to use `threadLocal.initialValue()` to somehow get a different value per thread.

Comment: toto2: Dude read what I have mentioned. I am saying exactly the same thing. :)